# In a Rails 3 session, how to save jquery state?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a multi-step form (a wizard) that I created using this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms.

A session is being used to remember all the info entered in the form. On one form page, I have a select box that has 3 options, and each option displays different form fields on the page. The options are: "Retail and Office" (both the retail and office fields are shown), "Office only" (only the office field is shown), "Retail only" (only the retail field is shown).

I used jquery to show and hide these fields based on the option selected in the select box. So here's the problem I'm having. Let's say, for example, that I've selected "Retail only" from the select box. The office field disappears, and only the retail field is shown. I enter the info into the field, and then proceed to the next step. However, when I hit the back button to go back to this step to edit it, both the office and retail fields are shown. The "Retail only" selection in the select box remains the same, and the info I entered is still there, but both fields are being shown.

I'm assuming that the problem is with the jquery, and not the rails session. Does this have to do with cookies? How do I correct this?

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#spaces").change(function(){
if ($("#spaces").val()=="Retail only") {$("#office_field").hide(); $("#retail_field").show(); }
if ($("#spaces").val()=="Office only") {$("#office_field").show(); $("#retail_field").hide(); }
if ($("#spaces").val()=="Retail and Office") {$("#office_field").show(); $("#retail_field").show(); }

});
```

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @uploads = Upload.all
  end

  def show
    @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    session[:upload_params] ||= {}
    @upload = Upload.new(session[:upload_params])
    @upload.current_step = session[:upload_step]
  end

  def create
    session[:upload_params].deep_merge!(params[:upload]) if params[:upload]
    @upload = Upload.new(session[:upload_params])
    @upload.current_step = session[:upload_step]
    if @upload.valid?
        if params[:back_button]
        @upload.previous_step
    elsif @upload.last_step?
        @upload.save if @upload.all_valid?
        else
        @upload.next_step
        end
        session[:upload_step] = @upload.current_step
    end
    if @upload.new_record?
        render "new"
    else
        session[:upload_step] = session[:upload_params] = nil
        flash[:notice] = "Upload saved"
        redirect_to @upload
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application.js you only have a 'change' event listener. What you need is to trigger
Your code to show/hide specific inputs is only bound to 'change' event of #spaces.

```
if ($("#spaces").val()=="Retail only") {$("#office_field").hide(); $("#retail_field").show(); }
if ($("#spaces").val()=="Office only") {$("#office_field").show(); $("#retail_field").hide(); }
if ($("#spaces").val()=="Retail and Office") {$("#office_field").show(); $("#retail_field").show(); }
```

Basically, you need to move this code into a function, and call this function on both page load and #spaces 'change':

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function retail_office_fields() {
    if ($("#spaces").val()=="Retail only") {$("#office_field").hide(); $("#retail_field").show(); }
    if ($("#spaces").val()=="Office only") {$("#office_field").show(); $("#retail_field").hide(); }
    if ($("#spaces").val()=="Retail and Office") {$("#office_field").show(); $("#retail_field").show(); }
  }

  retail_office_fields();

  $("#spaces").change(retail_office_fields);
});
```

It has nothing to do with sessions.